# F-bounded existential quantification

Tags: scala, existential-type, type-theory, f-bounded-polymorphism

I came across the existential quantification for F-bounded types while trying to understand scala's type system.

Let `A` be a type

```
trait A[F <: A[F]] { self: F => }
```

where `F` is the F-bounded self-type of `A`.

And `B` some subtype of `A`

```
case class B() extends A[B]
```

If I try to declare a `List` of `A` with existential quantification

```
val a: List[T] forSome { type T <: A[T] }
```

I get an error when assigning `a` a `List` of `B`. For some reason scala infers the type `List[A[Nothing]]`.

```
val a: List[T] forSome { type T <: A[T] } = List(B()) // type mismatch
```

When applying the simplification rule 4 (as described in the [scala-spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#existential-types)) the covariant occurrence of `T` may be replaced by the upper bound (here: `A[T]`)

```
val b: List[A[T]] forSome { type T <: A[T] } = List(B())
```

Both examples should be equivalent (if I have not misunderstood something), but the simplified one works just fine. Furthermore the following is also correct and should be equivalent:

```
val c: List[T forSome { type T <: A[T] }] = List(B())
```

But for some reason the type of `c` and the type of `b` are not equal.

So my question is: Is this a bug of the scala compiler or did I misunderstand something crucial?

**Edit**: Is my assumption correct, that the types of `c` and `b` are not equal, because the existential quantification in `c` does not see the covariant occurrence of `T`?